# javascript - Show symbol rather text in button

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm using a button to open a menu but I liked that this one shows up the menu symbol instead of the 'Menu' text.

As below:

`&amp;#9776;` ->  `☰`

`&amp;#10006;` -> `✖`

```js
function toggleText(button_id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(button_id);
  if (el.firstChild.data == "&#10006;") {
    el.firstChild.data = '&#9776;';
  } else {
    el.firstChild.data = "&#10006;";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="playlist-toggle" class="btn-playlist" onclick="toggleText(this.id);">&#9776;</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the actual text of the button rather than the child. Also note that the `innerHTML` can be either the entity or the rendered entity, so check that too:

```js
function toggleText(button_id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(button_id);
  if (["&#10006;", "✖"].includes(el.innerHTML)) {
    el.innerHTML = '&#9776;';
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = "&#10006;";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="playlist-toggle" class="btn-playlist" onclick="toggleText(this.id);">&#9776;</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `innerHTML` and pass the button element directly using `this`:

```js
function toggleText(button) {
  if (button.innerHTML == "&#10006;" || button.innerHTML == "✖") {
    button.innerHTML = '&#9776;';
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = '&#10006;';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="playlist-toggle" class="btn-playlist" onclick="toggleText(this);">&#9776;</button>
```

**Note:** The `innerHTML` can be either `&#10006;` or `✖`, so check for both.